# using ajax.load() to load Angular 6 index.html template

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angular

In a ASP.net view when certain link or button is clicked, it needs to load an Angular 5 or 6 application in a modal DIV, not a frame.  This is similar to using MVC controller to return partial view. Instead of posting to a controller action, I would like to use ajax.load('theAngularIndexHtml',{username:"aUsername" station:"aLocation" sta3n:"648" patientSID:"anId" patientIEN:"anIEN" patientName:"aPatientName" patientSSN4:"unknown" noteTitle:"Treatment Candidacy Note">}) bypassing the controller all together.  Is this possible?  If yes, how to set the parameter values into Angular app-root component's attributes.  Do I need to remove everything in the html template but app-root?  Angular requires a base tag in the head, how to deal with that? Here is the Angular index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Treatment Candidacy Note</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root userName="aUsername" station="aLocation" sta3n="648" patientSID="anId" patientIEN="anIEN" patientName="aPatientName" patientSSN4="unknown" noteTitle="Treatment Candidacy Note">
  </app-root>
</body>

</html>
​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution would be Single SPA Framework which helps you to bootstrap any popular framework such as Angular,Angular JS,React Vue and mount in to a div without IFrame.You have to do some registration based on the framework you are using , in your case it will **single-spa-angular** to bootstrap your application. Without boostrap angular , the component will not execute.

https://single-spa.js.org/docs/getting-started-overview.html

https://github.com/CanopyTax/single-spa-angular

https://medium.com/canopy-tax/a-step-by-step-guide-to-single-spa-abbbcb1bedc6

For communication to pass value , you can create your own event/subscribe mechanism or you can use redux or some other library also. In their github they are already explaining about this.

Live demo

https://single-spa.surge.sh/